How to print float number in Zephyr?
I am new to zephyr. I am working on a small project on nrf52832_mdk. There, I have to process and print float values in a driver. There, I added following flags and  I started getting float value prints

CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC=y
CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC_FLOAT_PRINTF=y
CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC_FLOAT_SCANF=y


Adding these flags are increasing my final execution file (binary) size a lot.
Background:
I want to implement DFU and mcuboot in my project. There I started getting error of exceeding flash size. So, On debugging, I get to know that mcuboot is dividing my flash into 4/5 segments  ( 1- Bootloader, 2- Image-0 slot, image-1 slot and 4-storage). So, I started figuring out which configuration is increasing my size (making it more than 200KB) for a small project. I found out that the above flags are increasing sizes a lot. I am anly using these flags for printing float values. Is there any alternative for printing the floats in zephyr. Furthermore, please tell me if these flags do some other things other than printing floats?
I want to find alternative of these flags for printing floats which has very less size
CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC=y

CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC_FLOAT_PRINTF=y

CONFIG_NEWLIB_LIBC_FLOAT_SCANF=y


See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191203/convert-float-to-string-without-sprintf
